# El codigo muestra este error: TypeError: write() got an unexpected keyword argument 'aling'

Tags: python

estoy comenzando a programar en el modulo turtle de python, he estado tratando de crear un juego similar a adventure de Warren Robinett pero la verdad que estoy perdidísimo. Mi codigo esta lleno de problemas, pero el mas importante es en la lineal 563, no me deja personalizar las letras del contador (después lo hare funcionar), también trato de hacer que las paredes sean menos confusas y su parte del codigo se menos larga pero ni idea, ademas de esome gustaria que los objetos como el zombie y el strider se muevan de una forma mas bonita o que persigan al jugador.
He aquí el código:

```
import turtle
import time
import random

posponer = 0.1

#configuracion de la ventana
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Aventura")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width = 600, height = 600)
wn.tracer(0)

#laberinto
pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(0, 0)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-20, 0)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(20, 0)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-40, 0)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(40, 0)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-100, 0)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(100, 0)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-100, 20)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(100, 20)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-100, 40)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(100, 40)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-100, 60)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(100, 60)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-100, 80)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(100, 80)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-120, 80)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(120, 80)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-140, 80)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(140, 80)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-160, 80)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(160, 80)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-180, 80)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(180, 80)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-200, 80)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(240, 80)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-220, 80)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(260, 80)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-240, 80)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(280, 80)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-260, 80)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(300, 80)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-280, 80)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-300, 80)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-100, -20)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(100, -20)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-100, -40)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(100, -40)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-100, -60)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(100, -60)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-100, -80)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(100, -80)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-100, -100)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(100, -100)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-120, -100)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(120, -100)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-140, -100)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(140, -100)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-160, -100)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-180, -100)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-240, -100)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-260, -100)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-280, -100)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(-300, -100)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(160, -100)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(180, -100)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(200, -100)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(220, -100)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(240, -100)
pared.direction = "stop"
pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(260, -100)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(280, -100)
pared.direction = "stop"

pared = turtle.Turtle()
pared.speed(0)
pared.shape("square")
pared.color("gray")
pared.penup()
pared.goto(300, -100)
pared.direction = "stop"

#jugador
jugador = turtle.Turtle()
jugador.speed(20)
jugador.shape("square")
jugador.color("white")
jugador.penup()
jugador.goto(0, -50)
jugador.direction = "up"

#funciones
def arriba():
   jugador.setheading(90)
   jugador.forward(20)

def derecha():
   jugador.setheading(0)
   jugador.forward(20)

def abajo():
   jugador.setheading(270)
   jugador.forward(20)

def izquierda():
   jugador.setheading(180)
   jugador.forward(20)


wn.onkeypress(arriba, "Up")
wn.onkeypress(derecha, "Right")
wn.onkeypress(abajo, "Down")
wn.onkeypress(izquierda, "Left")

wn.listen()

#mobs
mobs = []
count = 0

zombie = turtle.Turtle()
zombie.speed(0)
zombie.shape("square")
zombie.color("green")
zombie.penup()
zombie.goto(-220, 0)
zombie.direction = "stop"

strider = turtle.Turtle()
strider.speed(0)
strider.shape("square")
strider.color("red")
strider.penup()
strider.goto(220, 0)
strider.direction = "stop"

#texto
texto = turtle.Turtle()
texto.speed(0)
texto.color("gray")
texto.penup()
texto.hideturtle()
texto.goto(0,260)
texto.write("Score: 0       High Score: 0", aling = "center", font = ("Courier", 24, "normal"))

while True:
    wn.update()

    #colisiones mobs
    if count == 0:
        x = random.randint(-280, -120)
        y = random.randint(0, 0)
        time.sleep(0)
        zombie.goto(x, y)

    if jugador.distance(zombie) < 20 or jugador.distance(strider) < 20:
        time.sleep(1)
        jugador.goto(0, -50)
        jugador.direction = "stop"

turtle.done()
```

Comment: Adidale, la propiedad se llama align, no aling. Saludos.

Comment: @RodrigoN gracias, funciono. Llevaba semanas sin poder solucionarlo xd, por cierto, apenas pude leerlo